# How to insert a legend in grid.hexagons from hexbin in R

Tags: r

How do I to insert a legend in the example below?

```
library("grid")
library("hexbin")

set.seed(506)
x <- rnorm(10000)
y <- rnorm(10000)
z <- rnorm(100)
w <- rnorm(100)

xmin = min(x, z)
xmax = max(x, z)

ymin = min(y, w)
ymax = max(y, w)

df <- data.frame(x, y)
bin <- hexbin(df, xbins=30, xbnds= c(xmin, xmax) , ybnds= c(ymin, ymax))
graphic <- hboxplot(bin, xbnds= c(xmin, xmax) , ybnds= c(ymin, ymax))

pushHexport(graphic)
  grid.hexagons(bin, border = gray(.7))
  grid.points(z, w, pch=20, gp=gpar(col="blue")) #z and w are others data vectors to plot as points over de grid.hexagons.
upViewport()
```

I tried `grid.hexlegend` but it does not worked for me, maybe I did not done it right.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Why don't you use `gplot.hexbin` function?

Comment: or just don't use type = 'n', the legend is created by default

Comment: @rawr Inside which function?

Comment: @Pascal, I don't  use `gplot.hexbin` because I need the `xlim` and `ylim` can be edited, and in `hboxplot` they are, but don't in `gplot.hexbin` (as far as I know).

Comment: In your example, you don't use neither `xlim` nor `ylim`. And `hboxplot` doesn't support `type` argument. Please fix.

Comment: @rawr, I can't use `type = 'n'` because `hboxplot` don't do a graphic like `gplot.hexbin` do. So I have to do the graphic really in `grid.hexagons`, and `hboxplot` is basically to the axes.

Comment: @Pascal, I will put here the exact code I'm using (I'll take off this example).

Comment: @Pascal, I have changed the code now.

Comment: I get `Error in diff(ybnds) : object 'ymin' not found` when trying to `hexbin`.

Comment: @Pascal, I'm sorry, it is fixed now (I hope).

Comment: Hmm, sorry... In `grid.hexagons`, `Error in grid.hexagons(bin, border = gray(0.7), legend = 2) :  unused argument (legend = 2)`.

Comment: "legend = 2" was a missed test... I'm sorry again. Now I think it will work, @Pascal .